# Can't get image links to hover with translate3d

Tags: css, transform, transition, navigationbar, translate3d

I have a header with five images. I want the images to transition 10px up when hovered, but for some reason they just move up instantly and do not go up smoothly. I am using Google Chrome.

```
    .navbar img {
        position: relative;
        top: 0px;
        transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
    }

    .navbar img:hover {
        transform: translate3d(0px, -10px, 0px);
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, -10px, 0px);
    }
```

You can look up the site, http://pannariz.com. That's what it looks like

Answer (score 1):

You could try `-webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;` since you only apply transform.

YOu could also try `-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s ease-in-out;` as another solution for webkit browsers.